# How to use OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, service-accounts, google-iam

I would like to get access_token.
I read the following URL and found that it needs to be signed by JWT.

i get json key like this.

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

But RSA256 signing requires a public key, where can I get it?
I want to verify with [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/), but result is Invalid Signature.
The following, which was obtained by accessing client_x509_cert_url, was useless.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nxxxxxxxxx\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
```

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `client_x509_cert_url` contains a URL which contains multiple certificates. Each certificate contains a public key. Select the correct certificate based on the `private_key_id`. Then extract the public key.

I wrote the following code in 2018 to demonstrate how to create a Signed JWT using a service account and then verify the Signed JWT using Google public certificates. This example supports the Python OpenSSL and Cryptography libraries.

Once you have created a Signed JWT, you must exchange that for an Access Token.  My website has articles that detail that step also.

```
'''
This program creates and verifies a Signed JWT using the public certificate
'''

import time
import json
import base64
import jwt
import requests

# This example supports both libraries. Only one is required.

import OpenSSL.crypto

from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization


use_pyopenssl = True
# use_pyopenssl = False

json_filename = 'service-account.json'

# Google Endpoint for creating OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens from Signed-JWT
auth_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

# Set how long this token will be valid in seconds
expires_in = 3600   # Expires in 1 hour

scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"

# You can control what is verified in the JWT. For example to allow expired JWTs
# set 'verify_exp' to False
options = {
    'verify_signature': True,
    'verify_exp': True,
    'verify_nbf': True,
    'verify_iat': True,
    'verify_aud': True,
    'require_exp': False,
    'require_iat': False,
    'require_nbf': False
}

aud = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'

def load_private_key(json_cred):
    ''' Return the private key from the json credentials '''

    return json_cred['private_key']

def load_public_key(cert):
    ''' Extract the public key from the certificate '''

    if use_pyopenssl:
        obj = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(
                    OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
                    cert)

        pub_key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(
                    OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
                    obj.get_pubkey())

        # print('Public Key (pyOpenSSL)')
        # print(pub_key)

        return pub_key

    # print('Load certificate')
    cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert.encode('utf-8'), default_backend())

    # print('Get Public Key')
    pub_obj = cert_obj.public_key()

    # print(pub_obj)

    pub_key = pub_obj.public_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)

    # print('Public Key (cryptography)')
    # print(pub_key)

    return pub_key

def load_json_credentials(filename):
    ''' Load the Google Service Account Credentials from Json file '''

    # print('Opening:', filename)

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()

    return json.loads(data)

def load_public_certificates(url):
    ''' Load the public certificates for the client email address '''

    r = requests.get(url)

    if r.status_code != 200:
        return None

    return json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))

def create_signed_jwt(pkey, pkey_id, email, scope):
    ''' Create an AccessToken from a service account Json credentials file '''

    issued = int(time.time())
    expires = issued + expires_in   # expires_in is in seconds

    # Note: this token expires and cannot be refreshed. The token must be recreated

    # JWT Headers
    additional_headers = {
            'kid': pkey_id,
            "alg": "RS256",
            "typ": "JWT"    # Google uses SHA256withRSA
    }

    # JWT Payload
    payload = {
        "iss": email,       # Issuer claim
        "sub": email,       # Issuer claim
        "aud": auth_url,    # Audience claim
        "iat": issued,      # Issued At claim
        "exp": expires,     # Expire time
        "scope": scope      # Permissions
    }

    # Encode the headers and payload and sign creating a Signed JWT (JWS)
    sig = jwt.encode(payload, pkey, algorithm="RS256", headers=additional_headers)

    # print(sig)

    return sig

def pad(data):
    """ pad base64 string """

    missing_padding = len(data) % 4
    data += '=' * (4 - missing_padding)
    return data

def print_jwt(signed_jwt):
    """ Print a JWT Header and Payload """

    s = signed_jwt.decode('utf-8').split('.')

    print('Header:')
    h = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(pad(s[0])).decode('utf-8')
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(h), indent=4))

    print('Payload:')
    p = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(pad(s[1])).decode('utf-8')
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(p), indent=4))

def verify_signed_jwt(signed_jwt, pub_key):
    '''
    This function takes a Signed JWT and verifies it using a Google Json service account.
    '''

    # Verify the Signed JWT
    r = jwt.decode(signed_jwt, pub_key, algorithms=["RS256"], audience=aud, options=options)

    print('Decoded JWT:')
    print(json.dumps(r, indent=4))

def get_public_key(json_cred):
    '''
    Load the public certificates for the service account email address.
    Then compare the private_key_id to find the correct certificate.
    '''

    certs = load_public_certificates(json_cred['client_x509_cert_url'])

    for k in certs:
        if k == json_cred['private_key_id']:
            cert = certs[k]
            pub = load_public_key(cert)

            return pub

    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cred = load_json_credentials(json_filename)

    pub_certs = load_public_certificates(cred['client_x509_cert_url'])

    private_key = load_private_key(cred)

    # print('Private Key:')
    # print(private_key)

    public_key = get_public_key(cred)

    # print('Public Key:')
    # print(public_key)

    if public_key is None:
        print('Error: Cannot get public key')
        exit(1)

    s_jwt = create_signed_jwt(
            private_key,
            cred['private_key_id'],
            cred['client_email'],
            scopes)

    print_jwt(s_jwt)

    verify_signed_jwt(s_jwt, public_key)
```

Comment: I understand how to create a JWT, but do I need to verify it?
I think that it can be judged by exchanging access_token whether it is correct or not.

Comment: @mike - if you have a new question, post a new question. You asked `But RSA256 signing requires a public key, where can I get it? ...` so I answered that question and showed you how.

Comment: @mike Google Cloud OAuth is both very easy and very complicated depending on your understanding of OAuth and Google Authorization. You are just beginning to learn the basics. If your goal is to understand the building blocks, then yes, learning how to validate a Signed JWT is important as other services can use those tokens and you can write services that accept those tokens. Google OAuth Identity Tokens are becoming very popular and are Signed JWTs that you must verify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was able to figure out how to get the public key.
i learn jwt process to use my app and google cloud platform.
and why  need public key and verification process was needed.